# Sum of minimum values for each entry from a related table

Tags: sql, sqlite, min

Suppose I have 2 tables, query and rank. I would like to know if it is possible to find the sum of minimum values for each query in the rank table?

An entry to the rank table is made only where a user clicks a result for a particular query.

rank (id, key, value)
query (id, key, value)

where rank.id = query.id

Snapshot of 5 entries

```
rank table
-------------
Twp0+x1uZx1Y| Twp1PK8JWhng| 16 
Twp1KU6Pgxp4| Twp1VAF0jRyI| 5
Twp2KuoJWR-8| Twp2OR5X7h78| 1 
Twp354EADhYY| Twp4AQlqjxWg| 2

query table
------------
Twp0+x1uZx1Y| |sap
Twp0-XWZ3gpk| |
Twp1CIP+oh-Q| |
Twp1KU6Pgxp4| |virtual token
Twp14RxuSBzc| |
```

Comment: give some examples. What is on rank and query tables and what should be the result for it.

Comment: What DB are you using? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: I added some entries from both the rank and query tables @aF.

Comment: @eLearner and what should be the result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a subquery to join to the `query` table, like this:

```
select
    q.id,
    q.key,
    sum(r.minvalue) as valuesum
from
    query q
    left join (select min(value) as minvalue, id from rank group by id) r on
        q.id = r.id
group by
    q.id,
    q.key
```